# WampServer not working after Windows reinstall

Tags: wampserver, port80

WampServer was previously working. My IT department has reinstalled Windows. Now Wampserver does not work - it says, "local server none  of 3 services working".

With Apache, both Port 80 & 8080 are not working, I get -
"Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol."
"Your port 80 seems not actually used."
"Unable to initiate a socket connection."

Please can you suggest what I do.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3 services are `Apache(wampapache64)` `MySQL(wampmysqld64)` and `MariaDB('wampmariadb64')` PHP is not run as a service in WAMPServer

First check the mysql error log in \wamp64\logs if that does not help

- click the Wamp icon, then Apache > Service administration 'wampapache64' > Install Service.
- Then again Wamp icon, then Apache > Service administration 'wampapache64'  Start Service And finally Wamp icon > Restart All Services.

you can also do this :

Right-click on the WAMP icon, then Tools, then Create Wampserver Configuration Report (near the bottom). WAMP then opens and closes several cmd windows in generating the configuration report (wampConfReport.txt in the wamp directory).

Then again right-click on the WAMP icon, then Tools, then Wampserver Configuration Report. This will open the configuration report in your default text editor, and you can look through it to find what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you, I did Install Service & Start Service for Apache, MySql & Maria and it is now working. Thank you

Comment: @DavidGraham great, could you please mark the answer as accepted

Comment: You could also use `right click -> Tools -> Reinstall all services` assuming you have a resonably recent version of WAMPServer

Comment: That option worked for me when I did too

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having issues with trying to fix the red/orange wampserver icon not going green issue, I tried different solutions with the install/restart options in the wampserver menu, however only one option worked quick and fast!

TRY THIS: right click wampserver icon > tools > Reinstall all services
DONE!